# Reservación de Salas con Fecha y Hora SQL

Tags: sql-server

Estoy desarrollando un sistema de Apartado de Salas, tengo actualmente mi código funcionando, pero mi consulta SQL parece no funcionar correctamente en cierta situación

Esta es mi consulta ejemplo:

```
SELECT name, maxAvailablePlaces 
FROM [Attendance_Room] 
WHERE id NOT IN(
                SELECT idRoom 
                FROM Attendance_ApartadoSalas 
                WHERE (((fecha_inicial  BETWEEN '2021-12-21' AND '2021-12-26') OR 
                        (fecha_final  BETWEEN '2021-12-21' AND '2021-12-26')) AND 
                        ((hora_inicial BETWEEN '02:00:00' AND '05:00:00') OR 
                        (hora_final BETWEEN '02:00:00' AND '05:00:00')))
               );
```

Esta consulta funciona bien y no muestra las salas ocupadas en esos rangos de fecha y hora, pero cuando se hace la consulta con un minuto después de la hora de inicio, y un minuto antes de la hora final de alguna sala ya ocupada, dicha sala sí aparece, lo cuál no debería suceder, puesto que en ese rango la sala debería estar apartada.

Alguna ayuda?

Comment: ¿Has probado de ver que en la tabla `Attendance_ApartadoSalas` no haya cambios en las fechas y horas? Igual no es problema de la query sinó de las gestión que se este haciendo de esa tabla en algun momento dado.

Comment: Sí he revisado, pero no se hacen cambios en esa tabla para nada, sólo se guardan los registros, los cuales se toman para hacer la validación de si están apartadas las salas o no, el proyecto aún no está en producción, así que sólo he hecho las pruebas yo sin modificar las horas ni fechas de esa tabla

Comment: puedes mostrar un ejemplo donde no funciona?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar simplificar la consulta de esta manera creo que puede mejorar el resultado de la misma.

```
SELECT name, maxAvailablePlaces 
FROM [Attendance_Room] 
WHERE id NOT IN(
                SELECT idRoom 
                FROM Attendance_ApartadoSalas 
                WHERE fecha_inicial  >= '2021-12-21' and fecha_final  <= '2021-12-26' AND 
                        hora_inicial >= '02:00:00' and hora_final <= '05:00:00')
```